# Lazy load pages in UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a UIScrollView that contains large images and am using paging to scroll between images. In order to save memory, I am loading only one image before and after the currently visible one and loading/releasing new images after a scroll has completed.

The problem occurs when one scrolls quickly and `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` is not called.

How can I detect continuous scrolling?

I could check item location on every `scrollViewDidScroll` but this seems a bit heavy...

Comment: Is the solution of implementing decelerate related code from scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate is working for you?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a table view with custom cell content would work better for you, since it has a lot of logic built in for only loading cells that are visible as opposed to everything at once. There are lots of tutorials for how to manage table views in various ways.

Answer (score 0):

My temporary solution  is to cancel continuous scrolling by disabling scroll from when the user lifts the finger until scroll has completed.

```
-(void) scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [scrollView setScrollEnabled:NO];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGFloat pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width;
    int page = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 1.5) / pageWidth) + 1;
}
```

this method is called anytime the contentoffset changed whether programmatically or not.

From this method you can check to see if 'page' is the same as your current page, if not, you know you need to load something. The trick here is making images load without holding up the scrolling of the scrollview. That is where I am stuck.

the page calculation will change to next/previous  when you are half way to the next page

Answer (score 0):

if you are still looking for a solution... this what I do, it works really good having a good performance, too.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)sv willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
    if (!decelerate)
    {
        // load images and unload the ones that are not needed anymore
        [self someMethod]
    }
}


- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)sv
{
    // load images and unload the ones that are not needed anymore
    [self someMethod]
}
```

Comment: Even I have the same problem as Jean is having. I tried the method scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate: But, whenever scrollViewDidEndDecelerating is NOT getting called, scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate: also will not be called. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check both scrollViewDidEndDecelerating and scrollViewDidScroll.
When to user swipes and releases it letting to have the "momentum" scroll the first will be called at the and. If the user decides to stop the scroll with his finger by tapping to the tableview (or scroll comes to the most bottom, but I am not sure about that) the second event is fired.

Answer (score 0):

As per my experience, @jd291 is correct; I am using following callbacks successfully for most places

```
-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
```

but, the only case when a `callback` is not called is that you may not had set up the `delegate` properly.

Answer (score 0):

The WWDC 2010 has talked about this. They do a reuse of the sub scrollviews, alloc the missing image view in **scrollViewDidScroll:**. The video may help:

[Session 104 - Designing Apps with Scroll Views](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/?id=104)